# Updating configurable product throws error We can\'t find the quote item. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, quote, quoteitem

Basically  I am trying to update configurable product which has been successfully added to the shopping cart. I can see record of added configurable product item in my database `quote`, `quote_item` , `quote_item_option` tables after it has been added to my shopping cart. But when I update item it throws **We can't find the quote item**. Though quote item is present in the above mentioned tables. I am currently debugging `app\code\Company\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdateItemOptions.php`. I can see `echo $item->getProductId();` of added configurable product present in shoppingcart. Can anyone please guide me how to debug and solve this issue? I really want to learn how magento cart module works it would be really helpful. I also checked `\var\log\debug.log` but no errors or warnings.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Company\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Company\Core\Helper\CustomerHelper;
use Company\PricingAPI\Helper\PricingAPIHelper;
use Company\Core\Helper\QuoteHelper;
use \Company\Core\Helper\UploadHelper;
use \Company\Core\Helper\CookieHelper;

class UpdateItemOptions extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdateItemOptions
{
    protected $customerHelper;
    protected $pricingAPIHelper;
    protected $quoteHelper;
    protected $uploadHelper;
    protected $cookieHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        CustomerCart $cart,
        CustomerHelper $customerHelper,
        PricingAPIHelper $pricingAPIHelper,
        QuoteHelper $quoteHelper,
        UploadHelper $uploadHelper,
        CookieHelper $cookieHelper
    )
    {
        $this->customerHelper = $customerHelper;
        $this->pricingAPIHelper = $pricingAPIHelper;
        $this->quoteHelper = $quoteHelper;
        $this->uploadHelper = $uploadHelper;
        $this->cookieHelper = $cookieHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $scopeConfig, $checkoutSession, $storeManager, $formKeyValidator, $cart);
    }

    /**
     * Update product configuration for a cart item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (!isset($params['options'])) 
            $params['options'] = [];

        try 
        {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) 
            {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                    )->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $quoteItem = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
            $productInfo = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
          //$productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); /*****For All items *****/
            foreach ($productInfo as $item){
               echo $item->getProductId();
               echo'<br />';
            }
            if (!$quoteItem) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t find the quote item.'));
            }
       }
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what is app\code\Company\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdateItemOptions.php - a preference, or observer, but possible reason is - the original controller vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdateItemOptions.php:46 is actually depeting the old item and adding a new on this line:
`$item = $this->cart->updateItem($id, new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($params));`
Thus when you are trying to receive an item by its ID ($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) it can be already deleted here vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:1799